# Scoring function in JavaScript w/ only one initial prompt

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function

I can’t seem to figure out how to only prompt the user to select a scoring algorithm only once instead of every time.   I know that I’d like to be able to give the user the `initialPrompt` to select a scoring method, then prompt them for the word to score.  What I’m struggling with is separating the `initialPrompt` from the `runProgram` function so that it doesn’t keep calling it each time a word score is completed.

Here's what I've tried: 

1.  I've tried to call the `initialPrompt` outside of the `runProgram` function, but can't seem to get the return value of `intitalPrompt` so that I can use it in `runProgram`.  I've tried to set the `initialPrompt` to a variable inside `runProgram`.

2.  I've tried creating a new function that only scores a new word after the `runProgram` returns a score, so that I won't have to call `runProgram`, which in turn calls `initialPrompt`.

```
let word = '';


//code for the initial user prompt which asks them to choose a scoring algorithm.

function initialPrompt() {
  const input = require('readline-sync');
  let info = input.question(`Welcome to the Scrabble score calculator!

Which scoring algorithm would you like to use?

0 - Scrabble: The traditional scoring algorithm.
1 - Simple Score: Each letter is worth 1 point.
2 - Bonus Vowels: Vowels are worth 3 pts, and consonants are 1 pt.

Enter 0, 1, or 2:`)
  return info
}


// Code for runProgram function here:

function runProgram(scoringAlgorithms) {
  //initialPrompt();
  let num = initialPrompt();
  num = (Number(num));
  const readline = require('readline-sync');
  let word = readline.question(
    `Enter a word to score(Typing 'Stop' will end the program): `);
  word = word.toLowerCase();
  //console.log(word);
  //console.log(typeof num);
  //console.log(num===0);


//conditionals

  if (num === 0) {

    //console.log(initialPrompt);
    console.log("Scoring Choice: ", scoringAlgorithms[0].name);
    console.log(word);
    console.log(`Is worth ${scrabbleScoring(word, newPointStructure)} points`);
    runProgram()

  } else if (num === 1) {
    console.log(initialPrompt);
    console.log("Scoring Choice: ", scoringAlgorithms[1].name);
    console.log(word);
    console.log(`Is worth ${simpleScore(word)} points`);
    runProgram()

  } else if (num === 2) {
    console.log(initialPrompt);
    console.log("Scoring Choice: ", scoringAlgorithms[2].name);
    console.log(word);
    console.log(`Is worth ${bonusVowels(word)} points`);
    runProgram()

  } else if (num === 'Stop')
    console.log("Goodbye")
}
```

Here's what the results looks like when run...

```
Welcome to the Scrabble score calculator!

Which scoring algorithm would you like to use?
0 - Scrabble: The traditional scoring algorithm.
1 - Simple Score: Each letter is worth 1 point.
2 - Bonus Vowels: Vowels are worth 3 pts, and consonants are 1 pt.

Enter 0, 1, or 2:0
Enter a word to score(Typing 'Stop' will end the program): Programmer
Scoring Choice:  Scrabble Scoring
programmer
Is worth 17 points
Welcome to the Scrabble score calculator!

Which scoring algorithm would you like to use?

0 - Scrabble: The traditional scoring algorithm.
1 - Simple Score: Each letter is worth 1 point.
2 - Bonus Vowels: Vowels are worth 3 pts, and consonants are 1 pt.

Enter 0, 1, or 2:
```

This is what I want it to look like:

```
Welcome to the Scrabble score calculator!

Which scoring algorithm would you like to use?
0 - Scrabble: The traditional scoring algorithm.
1 - Simple Score: Each letter is worth 1 point.
2 - Bonus Vowels: Vowels are worth 3 pts, and consonants are 1 pt.

Enter 0, 1, or 2: 0
Enter a word to score(Typing 'Stop' will end the program): Programmer
Scoring Choice:  Scrabble Scoring (Or whatever scoring algorithm the user chooses) 
Your word is worth: 17 points

Enter a word to score(Typing 'Stop' will end the program):
```

Here is the full sample code:
https://repl.it/@AbbyHowe/A-2-Scrabble-Scorer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; your `runProgram` function seems to call the `initialPrompt` function only once, not in a loop, so your `runProgram` function must be being called multiple times. We will not be able to answer the question without seeing a complete piece of code to work out what it's doing; please post a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks @kaya3 Here it is: https://repl.it/@AbbyHowe/A-2-Scrabble-Scorer

Comment: You will need to edit your question to include the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use recursion to run the code in a loop, use a `while` loop. You can break out of the loop with `break`.

Also, you comparing `word` to `stop`, not `num`.

```js
function runProgram(scoringAlgorithms) {
  //initialPrompt();
  let num = initialPrompt();
  num = (Number(num));
  const readline = require('readline-sync');
  while (true) {
    let word = readline.question(
      `Enter a word to score(Typing 'Stop' will end the program): `);
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    if (word == "stop") {
      console.log("Goodbye");
      break;
    }
    if (num === 0) {
      //console.log(initialPrompt);
      console.log("Scoring Choice: ", scoringAlgorithms[0].name);
      console.log(word);
      console.log(`Is worth ${scrabbleScoring(word, newPointStructure)} points`);
    } else if (num === 1) {
      console.log(initialPrompt);
      console.log("Scoring Choice: ", scoringAlgorithms[1].name);
      console.log(word);
      console.log(`Is worth ${simpleScore(word)} points`);
    } else if (num === 2) {
      console.log(initialPrompt);
      console.log("Scoring Choice: ", scoringAlgorithms[2].name);
      console.log(word);
      console.log(`Is worth ${bonusVowels(word)} points`);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making scoring algo a variable and in runProgram() make a check to see if the variable is set. If set than don't call the inital prompt

```
let word = '';
let scoringAlgo = ''

//code for the initial user prompt which asks them to choose a scoring algorithm.

function initialPrompt() {
  const input = require('readline-sync');
  let info = input.question(`Welcome to the Scrabble score calculator!

Which scoring algorithm would you like to use?

0 - Scrabble: The traditional scoring algorithm.
1 - Simple Score: Each letter is worth 1 point.
2 - Bonus Vowels: Vowels are worth 3 pts, and consonants are 1 pt.

Enter 0, 1, or 2:`)
  return info
}


// Code for runProgram function here:

function runProgram(scoringAlgorithms) {
  //initialPrompt();
  if (scoringAlgo == ''){
    let num = initialPrompt();
    num = (Number(num));
  }
  else {
    let num = scoringAlgo;
  }

  const readline = require('readline-sync');
  let word = readline.question(
    `Enter a word to score(Typing 'Stop' will end the program): `);
  word = word.toLowerCase();
  //console.log(word);
  //console.log(typeof num);
  //console.log(num===0);


//conditionals

  if (num === 0) {

    //console.log(initialPrompt);
    console.log("Scoring Choice: ", scoringAlgorithms[0].name);
    console.log(word);
    console.log(`Is worth ${scrabbleScoring(word, newPointStructure)} points`);
    runProgram()

  } else if (num === 1) {
    console.log(initialPrompt);
    console.log("Scoring Choice: ", scoringAlgorithms[1].name);
    console.log(word);
    console.log(`Is worth ${simpleScore(word)} points`);
    runProgram()

  } else if (num === 2) {
    console.log(initialPrompt);
    console.log("Scoring Choice: ", scoringAlgorithms[2].name);
    console.log(word);
    console.log(`Is worth ${bonusVowels(word)} points`);
    runProgram()

  } else if (num === 'Stop')
    console.log("Goodbye")
}
```

Comment: Thank you @irtazaakram You will see that in full code link that I set the `scoringAlgorithms` to an array of three numbers which is what I compare `num` to in the conditionals section.  That part works the way I expect it to work. I would like help in figuring out a way to not continually call the `initialPrompt` when I call the `runProgram` function.